# Running Client program and API in same Docker Machine

Tags: docker

I had an API which is running as one container and Client program running as another container. API is accessible on the remote machine but Client container not communicating with API. It's not communicating because of Socket Error

Comment: So you have two containers, one with API and another - with Client, and Client could not access API because of socker error? Is it possible that you've missed EXPOSE for the API?

Comment: I had used *Expose* in the API Docker File, API is accessible in Remote, I had fixed this adding docker0 in iptaple @Karatheodory